# Is there any kind of security in Nearby Connections?

Tags: android, google-nearby, google-nearby-connections

I was wondering if *Nearby Connections* implements some type of internal authentication, cryptography or anything like it. And if it's possible to disable this.

PS: my app is a "proof of concept" and I would like to know if the time constraints are met by the Nearby API.

```
version: com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:17.0.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is encryption (see https://github.com/google/ukey2). It is not possible to disable it, although if you do not properly verify the tokens when accepting the connection then assume the encryption is broken.